# Error al importar pandas_datareader, "ImportError: cannot import name 'is_list_like'"

Tags: python, pandas, python-import

Luego de instalar con pip  `pandas_datareader`, al momento de importarlo me genera el siguiente error:

```
>>> import pandas_datareader as web
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas_datareader as web
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .data import (DataReader, Options, get_components_yahoo,
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader.fred import FredReader
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\fred.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.common import is_list_like
ImportError: cannot import name 'is_list_like'
```

¿A qué se debe y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Hay un nombre de un paquete del core que tienes que redefinir , parece ser un error del módulo, prueba hacer los imports de la siguiente forma:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
import pandas_datareader as web
```

Comment: Hice el cambio , pero igual nada:                                                    

Exception: Request Error!: 404 : Not Found

Comment: Eso ya dejaría de ser un error del módulo. Pero el error que tenias inicialmente `ImportError: cannot import name 'is_list_like'` parece que ya no causa problemas

Comment: Puedes dejar tu código para ver por qué te da esa excepción

Comment: import datetime as dt                                                                     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
import pandas_datareader.data as web

style.use('ggplot')

start = dt.datetime(2000,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2016,12,31)

# df = Data frame
df = web.DataReader('TSLA', 'yahoo', start, end)
print(df.head())

Comment: Y este es el error que me arroja ahora

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getting_stock_price_data2.py", line 14, in <module>
df = web.DataReader('TSLA', 'morningstar', start, end)
File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 391, in DataReader
session=session, interval="d").read()
File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\mstar\daily.py", line 219, in read
df = self._dl_mult_symbols(symbols=symbols)
File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\mstar\daily.py", line 130, in _dl_mult_symbols
resp.status_code, resp.reason))
Exception: Request Error!: 404 : Not Found

Answer (score 0):

La excepción se debe a a que `is_list_like` se ha movido de `pandas.core.common` a [`pandas.api.types`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/pull/520/commits) en la versión 0.23 de Pandas. El error está reportado en el [repositorio de pandas_datareader](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/pull/520) y corregido en la versión dev actual.

En el momento que se genere la nueva versión estable de la biblioteca  y sea subida a PyPi el error será corregido. Mientras tanto, puede hacer lo siguiente:

- Instalar la versión dev desde GitHub:

  ```
  $ python -m pip install git+https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader.git
  ```
- Crear un alias antes del import en tu script principal:

  ```
  >>> import pandas as pd
  >>> pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like 
  >>> import pandas_datareader
  ```
- Modificar el código fuente del paquete en el directorio dónde lo tengas instalado indicando el `import` correcto, de forma similar a como se ha hecho en el commit enlazado arriba.
- Instalar una versión anterior a la 0.23 de Pandas:

  ```
  $ python -m pip install pandas==0.22 --force-reinstall
  ```